# Azure Functions Cron Expression Won't Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have the following cron expression for my Azure Functions' function:

```
0 0 8,12,16 * * 1-5
```

It doesn't seem to ever kick off. I pulled down the [Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions), and threw my expression into their unit tests and confirmed that it was working in there.

I also confirmed that `0 0 */6 * * 1-5` was working, but I'd rather this only run at 8AM, noon, and 4PM.

Any ideas on why this wouldn't be working?

Edit: In regards to Fabio's answer, I tried removing the seconds component and got the following error message in Azure.
[image: Azure Error Message]

Comment: Cameron, continuing here. What plan are you running your app on? Is this on the consumption (dynamic) plan or an App Service plan?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante I'm using the consumption plan.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your Function App name, either directly or indirectly (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) so we can take a closer look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is currently setting the Function App timezone to Central Time, (using `APSETTING_WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`) which is currently impacted by a bug we are tracking here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/995

Removing the timezone configuration (and adjusting the expression accordingly, to work on UTC) should address the problem

Thank you for the patience and please feel free to follow the issue to track progress on this.